# What is a Losungs-Schein?

Tags: translation

I have 1856 document about military service, titled "Loosungs-Schein"? What does that mean? A certificate, yes, but what does "Loosungs" mean?

Comment: You use two different spellings in your question, which one is the one on the document?

Comment: Both spellings exists on historical documents. Before the Duden standardization of German orthography in the early 20th century there usually existed a range of admissible spellings to express phonetic characteristics. The doubled `o` stands for a long vowel.

Answer (score 9):

Didn’t know the term, but a quick search suggests that this used to be a document that each person received when registering for military service (as the result of the *Musterung*) and that served as an ID during their service.

The closest meaning in nowadays German seems to be the 1st one listed in my *Österreichisches Wörterbuch, 39. Auflage* (the official dictionary for Austrian German):

> **Losung**  die, ~/~en: ein Wort als Erkennungszeichen (Losungswort)

which basically means password.

[Duden online](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Losung_Kennwort_Spruch#Bedeutung2) has a similar entry:

> 2. vereinbartes Kennwort zum Passieren der Wachen

The combination of *Losung* (a password that allows you to get past the guards) and *Schein* (a document — *Führerschein, Geldschein* etc.) means something like “A document that serves as a passport at (military) guard posts”.

Answer (score 7):

The *Losungsschein* (old spelling *Loosungsschein*, orthographically expressing the long vowel) represents a certificate by local German military authority about the number male subjects  eligible to military service had received in a drawing (German *Losverfahren*; *Losung* [in today’s idiom, *Auslosung*]) that was held to decide on who had to join active service.

The German military system (ie. the military of the predecessor political entities of the German Reich) has traditionally been based on mandatory service of male subjects. The motive behind this drawing had been the perennial surplus of prospective conscripts for active service. A high number in the drawing would spare you from active service.

The Losungsschein — in particular in case you were lucky and you fell into the high number batch — also served as a military id during the service time (= period of time while you were eligible for active service, basically determined by age).

There is no corresponding notion in today’s German military administration.

**Caveat**

This information has been gleaned from the net based on a google search. I am by no means an expert of military affairs and/or history (nor do I want to become one), so please pardon any inaccuracies of the presentation.

References:

- [Synopsis (in German)](http://www.agw14-18.de/formgesch/formatio_rek.html)
- [Original copy](http://www.dhm.de/datenbank/img.php?img=zd014234&format=1)
- [Another original copy](http://www.dhm.de/datenbank/img.php?img=ha945343&format=1)

Comment: Note that *traditionally* means *[from 1813](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wehrpflicht_in_Deutschland#Geschichte)*.

Comment: @Jan Thx for the reference. That makes the first of the original copies quite an early example.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my guess for "Loosungs-Schein", which was [Draft-Lottery] Certificate. I have an example of this document, about 23cm x 36cm, where the bottom half is the Lossungs-Schein issued 1856, and the top half is the companion Gestellungs-Attest with entries for 1856, 1857, and 1858.